# Strange results from aggregation by date field in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose. Here is my aggregation code:

```
var query = { created: { '$gte': Thu Jan 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) } }
Model.aggregate([
    { $match: query },
    { $group: {
        _id: {
            day: { $dayOfMonth: '$created' },
            month: { $month: '$created' },
            year: { $year: '$created' },
        },
        amount: { $sum: 1 },
    date: { $min: '$created' },
     }}],
        function(err,result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    );
```

This code groups Filters model by `created` field and then groups them (and counts) by `created` field. The result is:

```
[ { _id: { day: 24, month: 1, year: 2014 },
    amount: 13,
    date: Fri Jan 24 2014 06:46:57 GMT+0100 (CET) },
  { _id: { day: 23, month: 1, year: 2014 },
    amount: 46,
    date: Thu Jan 23 2014 02:52:24 GMT+0100 (CET) },
  { _id: { day: 22, month: 1, year: 2014 },
    amount: 1,
    date: Thu Jan 23 2014 00:18:18 GMT+0100 (CET) } ]
```

Why date `Thu Jan 23 2014 00:18:18 GMT+0100` has been grouped to `{ day: 22, month: 1, year: 2014 }` ??? I guess this might something to do with timezone?

Answer (score 0):

You guessed right. The dates get bucketed by UTC times.

If all the values are from the same timezone (CET for example), and you want to bucket by days in that zone, you can add seconds to your date value (+3600 for CET).
If you have values from many timezones, then you need to think about how you want to aggregate your results.

See the following Jira ticket (SERVER-6310) for a discussion on the subject and some available workarounds.

Comment: By saying that I could `add 3600 seconds to date` you mean that I would have to modify dates in database in order to receive correct aggregation results? And then after aggregation substract 3600 sec to get time in my timezone?

Comment: The first thing you need to decide is if you want to aggregate with UTC times, times per timezones or times for CET (if all your data is in this time zone).
For the first option, the aggregation framework is doing that automatically.
For the second option, add the number of seconds corresponding to each time zone.
For the third option, add 3600 to all your timestamps.

Comment: Now, as how you add seconds to the timestamps, you do not want to add and subtract values from your 'created' field. Instead create a new field 'created_adjusted' and store the adjusted value in it. You need to compute that field only once, either at insertion, or with a regular job adding the missing ones.